# Agregar javascript a Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

estoy intentando agregar un fragmento de código javascript al index.html.erb de una de mis vistas llamada 'Turns'. Hasta ahí no tengo problemas porque meto el siguiente código dentro del archivo html y funciona todo genial:

```
/*
                     Please consider that the JS part isn't production ready at all, I just code it to show the concept of merging filters and titles together !
                     */
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('.filterable .btn-filter').click(function () {
                            var $panel = $(this).parents('.filterable'),
                                    $filters = $panel.find('.filters input'),
                                    $tbody = $panel.find('.table tbody');
                            if ($filters.prop('disabled') == true) {
                                $filters.prop('disabled', false);
                                $filters.first().focus();
                            } else {
                                $filters.val('').prop('disabled', true);
                                $tbody.find('.no-result').remove();
                                $tbody.find('tr').show();
                            }
                        });

                        $('.filterable .filters input').keyup(function (e) {
                            /* Ignore tab key */
                            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                            if (code == '9')
                                return;
                            /* Useful DOM data and selectors */
                            var $input = $(this),
                                    inputContent = $input.val().toLowerCase(),
                                    $panel = $input.parents('.filterable'),
                                    column = $panel.find('.filters th').index($input.parents('th')),
                                    $table = $panel.find('.table'),
                                    $rows = $table.find('tbody tr');
                            /* Dirtiest filter function ever ;) */
                            var $filteredRows = $rows.filter(function () {
                                var value = $(this).find('td').eq(column).text().toLowerCase();
                                return value.indexOf(inputContent) === -1;
                            });
                            /* Clean previous no-result if exist */
                            $table.find('tbody .no-result').remove();
                            /* Show all rows, hide filtered ones (never do that outside of a demo ! xD) */
                            $rows.show();
                            $filteredRows.hide();
                            /* Prepend no-result row if all rows are filtered */
                            if ($filteredRows.length === $rows.length) {
                                $table.find('tbody').prepend($('<tr class="no-result text-center"><td colspan="' + $table.find('.filters th').length + '">No result found</td></tr>'));
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

Ahora lo que quiero y he leído que ese fragmento de código puedo sacarlo de este archivo html y agregarlo dentro de una carpeta 'assets/javascripts/' Lo que no he podido es real izarlo, encuentro la ubicación y todo pero no se si es que tengo que crear un archivo y tampoco se como incluirlo en mi archivo html. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Crea el archivo con el nombre que sea en _assets/javascripts_ y pon el código ahí. Si estás utilizando el _asset pipeline_ (imagino que así es, ¿qué versión de Rails tienes?) es todo lo que necesitas hacer, solo asegúrate que estés cargando los _assets_ en _views/layouts/application.html.erb_ (la línea es algo similar a `<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track": "reload" %>`.

Comment: Hola @Gerry ! Rails 5.2.3 es mi versión. Ahi voy a intentar con lo que me dijiste.

Comment: Para agregar estilos CSS como seria?

Comment: En la [documentación de rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline) sale como hacer lo que requieres. Saludos